# Connect to Cloud SQL using Sql2o in Google Cloud Endpoint

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints, google-cloud-sql

I'm trying to connect to cloud sql inside google cloud endpoint and using lightweight jdbc wrapper `sql2o` as data access method.

```
@Api(name = "questionapi", version = "v1", description = "question api")
public class QuestionService {

    private static Sql2o sql2o = new Sql2o(
            "jdbc:mysql://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:3306/xxxxx", "root",
            "xxxxxxx");

    @ApiMethod(name = "get", httpMethod = HttpMethod.GET)
    public List<Question> get() {

        String q = "select * from questions";

        try (Connection conn = sql2o.open()) {
            return conn.createQuery(q).executeAndFetch(Question.class);
        }
    }
```

After the app is running, I can visit `localhost:8888/_ah/api/explorer` to try the api. However, there is an error says:

```
org.sql2o.Sql2oException: Could not acquire a connection from DataSource - No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:3306/xxxxx
```

How can I solve this issue?

**EDIT:**

[image]

After change to maven project and I got this new error message:

```
503 Service Unavailable

- Show headers -

{
 "error": {
  "message": "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl",
  "code": 503,
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "backendError",
    "message": "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl"
   }
  ]
 }
}
```

**EDIT**

It's a new day, I still stuck here.

What I did is I use maven to download the **endpoints-skeleton-archetype** project, it's a new, empty Cloud Endpoints backend API project ready for use, with required files and directories.

I immediately deploy it to app engine, and try to return a meaningful value. It worked, a simple 'hellp world' string will be returned.

Next, I tried to connect to cloud sql using jdbc. In order to do that, I followed the tutorial [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/cloud-sql/#enable_connector_j)
to add `<use-google-connector-j>true</use-google-connector-j>` into **appengine-web.xml**

and I try different combination of connection string

```
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.GoogleDriver");
        String url = "jdbc:google:mysql://xxxxxxxxxxxx:xxxxx?user=root";

        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
        ResultSet rs = conn.createStatement().executeQuery("SELECT 1 + 1");
```

[image]

After all these, I still get this error message.

```
    503 Service Unavailable

- Show headers -

{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "backendError",
    "message": "java.lang.NullPointerException"
   }
  ],
  "code": 503,
  "message": "java.lang.NullPointerException"
 }
}
```

Comment: Also having this problem but can't fix it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error occurs when the jdbc driver is not found in the classpath. How are you managing dependencies? Do you use maven? The error should be fixed if you add the mysql jdbc driver to your list of dependencies.

I have another comment to your code, which has nothing to do with your question. But here it comes anyway.
The codeline below has a connection leak as you never closes the connection. This will eventually deplete the connection pool and your application will hang.

`return sql2o.open().createQuery(q).executeAndFetch(Question.class);`

This is the correct way of doing it when using sql2o:

`try (Connection con = sql2o.open()) {
    return con.createQuery(q).executeAndFetch(Question.class);
}`

Comment: I changed to maven project and added sql2o jar and connector j jar files to maven dependency. now I have a new error message.

Comment: Did you enable mysql connector on GAE? https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/cloud-sql/#enable_connector_j

Comment: Yes, I did add a new line of XML. I'm trying to connect to database using the method from documentation. After that I try to use sql2o. Any idea? Are you from google?

Comment: google says 'The MySQL Connector/J is available in Google App Engine, but it's not included in an app unless the app explicitly asks for it'. so should I still include the mysql-connector-java-5.1.6.jar into maven dependency ?

Comment: I can connect to cloud sql using jdbc now. But I still can't connect to cloud sql using sql2o, I found that sql2o has dependency on javax.naming.* class, but this class is not inclueded or supported by google app engine. There is a whitelist listed by google what class are supported by google app engine. here is the link: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/jrewhitelist

Comment: You are right! The javax.naming package is not available from gae. I have submitted an issue on the sql2o github page: https://github.com/aaberg/sql2o/issues/168 .

Comment: It is, if the use of javax.name package is removed from future versions of sql2o. The javax.naming package is only used for jndi lookup, which could just as well be handled by the application using sql2o.